# Rule Example in Backgammon

Tags: backgammon

I don't know of a scenario that is an example: if either number can be played but not both, the player must play the larger one. Can someone please explain when this rule should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make it an easy and fast rule, a player MUST play the larger part of the roll, if he can play ONLY one part of his dice.

In the above example, if red rolls 21, he MUST play 3/1, and is not permitted to play 3/2, this is not a choice, its a mandatory move.

Answer (score 0):

Player A has 14 stones on Player B's one-point, and a fifteenth stone on his 3-point.

Player B has a wall at least two points long running back from his two-point.

If player A rolls 1-2 he can move his fifteenth stone either one or two points (respectively to either the two-point or one-point), but cannot move it three (ie remove it) because not al his stones are in his Home board yet.

[image: example]

Comment: Also, there could just be another wall 3 spaces away from the lone stone.

Comment: Position is right (although pretty unusual), but description is misleading.